# Domain names not resolving on CentOS webserver

Tags: centos7, resolv.conf

I have a small webhosting VPS running CentOS Linux 7.9.2009 (Core).

I'm also running Plesk Obsidian Version 18.0.52

Here is my /etc/resolv.conf file:

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 71.19.155.120
nameserver 71.19.155.215
```

(The last 2 nameservers are provided by my VPS host)

From the CLI I cannot dig, ping, traceroute, etc... even my own hostname.

I noticed this yesterday and now my clients are reporting various issues that I imagine are related (emails stuck in queue, can't log into local WordPress installations, WooCommerce issues).

```
# ping google.ca
ping: google.ca: Name or service not known
```

and

```
# dig www.Google.com @8.8.8.8

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-26.P2.el7_9.8 <<>> www.Google.com @8.8.8.8
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

What the heck is going on?

Comment: I can't even ping 8.8.8.8

So weird.

Comment: A clue. dig www.google.com @2001:4860:4860::8888 works!

Comment: Seems your IPv4 is busted - what's the output of `ip -4 a` and `ip -4 r`

Comment: 1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 71.19.145.6/24 brd 71.19.145.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 71.19.146.141/24 brd 71.19.146.255 scope global eth0:0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Comment: 3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Comment: default via 71.19.146.1 dev eth0
71.19.145.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 71.19.145.6
71.19.146.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 71.19.146.141
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0 scope link metric 1002
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1

Comment: you should add that *to the question* where it can be readable

Comment: thanks, @JaromandaX. I will remember that for next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand how or why (as we don't used nginx), but this issue seems to have stemmed from the nginx service not starting properly on my server.

Once that issue was repaired all of the other issues went away.